# Index rebuild from table cursor

Tags: oracle, indexing

Friends... continuing my debugging frenzy week...
I have got curTable part working with the help of user @Bob... now trying next phase of this testing and trying to rebuild all indexes at a time of the owner.table which were identified by rec1.curTable cursor.

I have spent some time and again stuck with cursor part, could somebody please help or point my mistake?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE moveTbl (OldTbs in varchar2, NewTbs in varchar2)
    AUTHID CURRENT USER
IS
  CURSOR curTable IS
    SELECT owner, table_name, tablespace_name
      FROM dba_tables
      WHERE tablespace_name = OldTbs
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;
rec1 curTable%ROWTYPE;

  CURSOR curIndex (TabOwn IN varchar2, TabNam IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  SELECT table_owner, table_name, owner, index_name, tablespace_name
  FROM dba_indexes
  WHERE table_owner = rec1.owner
  AND table_name = rec1.table_name;
rec2 CurIndex%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  FOR rec1 IN curTable LOOP
    dbms_output.putline(rec1.owner || '.' || rec1.table_name);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || rec1.owner || '.' || rec1.table_name ||
                      ' move tablespace ' || NewTbs;

   -- Starting curIndex
     OPEN curIndex (rec1.owner, rec1.table_name); LOOP
        BEGIN
          FETCH curIndex into rec2;
        EXIT when curIndex%NOTFOUND 

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE ('alter index '||rec2.owner||'.'rec2.index_name||' rebuild tablespace '|| NewTbs ||' online')
      END;

      END LOOP; -- index cursor loop
      CLOSE curIndex;   

END;
  END LOOP;  --curTable for loop
END moveTbl;
```

Comment: Based on `CREATE OR REPLACE`, the string concatenation with `||` and `VARCHAR2`, I'm assuming this is for **Oracle** - added the appropriate tag

Comment: @marc_s, that's true

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly? And why are you concatenating in the `where` clause rather than comparing the two columns separately? Have you changed cursor types for a reason, and why the inner begin/end block inside the second cursor loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what issues you're facing, but the query for your second cursor isn't right; `rec1` isn't in scope. You should be using the cursor parameters:

```
CURSOR curIndex (TabOwn IN varchar2, TabNam IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  SELECT table_owner, table_name, owner, index_name, tablespace_name
  FROM dba_indexes
  WHERE table_owner = TabOwn
  AND table_name = TabNam;
```

The `rec1` declaration from row type isn't needed with the cursor synatx you've chosen; `rec2` is unless you change that to use the same loop type. You don't need the begin/end in the inner loop though. And you seem to have an extra `end` floating around too. You could simplify that a bit to:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec1 IN curTable LOOP
    dbms_output.putline(rec1.owner || '.' || rec1.table_name);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || rec1.owner || '.' || rec1.table_name ||
                      ' move tablespace ' || NewTbs;

    FOR rec2 IN curIndex (rec1.owner, rec1.table_name) LOOP

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter index '||rec2.owner||'.'rec2.index_name
        ||' rebuild tablespace '|| NewTbs ||' online';

    END LOOP; -- index cursor loop
  END LOOP; -- outer table loop
END moveTbl;
```

You then wouldn't need to declare `rec2` either.

Comment: that is exactly right, I separated concatenating but still didn't work and as per your comment on cursor parameter it did the trick. I missed TAbOwn & TabName..... working/testing from home sometime gets boring and when you are not strong with pl/sql it gets really really tricky.